# how to call model class in controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

mvc4

this is my controller class in controller folder

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /User/
    private static Users _users = new Users();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_users._userList);
    }

    public ActionResult UserAdd()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UserAdd(UserModels userModel)
    {
        _users.CreateUser(userModel);
        return View();
    }

}
```

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'Users' could not be found
>
> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'UserModels' could not be found

this is my user class in model folder

```
 public class Users
    {
        public Users()
        {
            _userList.Add(new UserModels
            {
                FirstName = "birbal ",
                LastName = "kumar",
                Address = "new delhi",
                Email = "example@gmail.com",
                DOB = Convert.ToDateTime("2/11/1991"),
                salary = 8000
            });
         }
    }
```

this is my usermodel class in model folder

```
public class UserModels
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="First name is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set;  }
    [Range(100,1000000)] 
    public decimal salary { get; set; }
}
```

how to remove my errors

Comment: Try to import your model folder by using the `using` statement
`using Yournamespace.Model`

Comment: do you have namespace block before class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not included namespace of Models.

Just Right Click on **Users** class name in the controller and go to Resolve and from their include its namespace in controller class.

If you want to do explicitly then, your project namespace assming MyProject, do like this:

```
using MyProject.Models;


public class UserController : Controller
{
   private static Users _users = new Users();
}
```

or you can use **Fully Qualified Name** like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
  private static MyProject.Models.Users _users = new MyProject.Models.Users();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your model folder by using the **using** statement if yor models are in the same project. otherwise add the reference of the project where your models are available.

```
using Yournamespace.Model;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to the assembly containing the model classes, and also add a "using XXXXX" statement to your file with the namespace of your model classes.